# Two WordPress Multisite installation in different subdirectories

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url-rewriting, multisite

I have a WordPress Multisite installation here: mydomain.com
I use it to have different languages like:

```
 mydomain.com/fr
 mydomain.com/de
 ...
```

Now we are changing design, but we would like to do step by step, language by language.

So we have installed another Wordpress Multisite in the folder /new, that it's working perfectly with sites like

```
 mydomain.com/new/fr
 mydomain.com/new/de
 ...
```

We would like to redirect JUST THE FRENCH language to the new wordpress. I've tried with this .htaccess in the root folder (based on the information in [Wordpress documentation](https://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Method_I_.28Without_URL_change.29):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/fr/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^fr(.*)$ /new/fr/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$
RewriteRule ^fr(/)?$ /new/fr/index.php [L]
```

But that is giving a "Error establishing a database connection". It's weird because, as I explained, the site mydomain.com/new/fr is working perfectly.

NOTE: we don't want to use subdomains, I know that would make a different approach and solution ;-)

EDIT: The error is because this query

```
SELECT  blog_id FROM wp_blogs  WHERE domain IN ( 'mydomain.com' ) AND path IN ( '/fr/', '/' )  ORDER BY CHAR_LENGTH(path) DESC LIMIT 1
```

I guess, the redirection is working well, but when the wordpress inside "new" directory tries to determine which blog to visit, it reads the URL and it's in "/" really, since the redirection rule has an [L] and keeps the original URL in the apache environment variables.

Comment: Did you try with `R=301`?

Answer (score 3):

If you activated Multisite on WordPress 3.5 or later, you can follow the [documentation setup](https://codex.wordpress.org/Multisite_Network_Administration) in the section `.htaccess and Mod Rewrite`

According to the documentation:

> .htaccess and Mod Rewrite Unlike Single Site WordPress, which can work
>   with "ugly" Permalinks and thus does not need Mod Rewrite, MultiSite
>   requires its use to format URLs for your subsites. This necessitates
>   the use of an .htaccess file, the format of which will be slightly
>   different if you're using SubFolders or SubDomains. The examples below
>   are the standard .htaccess entries for WordPress SubFolders and
>   SubDomains, when WordPress is installed in the root folder of your
>   website. If you have WordPress in its own folder, you will need to
>   change the value for RewriteBase appropriately.